# Style links that use onclick action to open in new tab

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I use the following to indicate when a link opens in a new tab:

```
a[target="_blank"]:after {
    content: " \2197";
}
```

I also have links that open with an onclick action:

```
onclick="javascript:this.target="_blank""
```

As these links are generated by webparts (this is a SharePoint site) there is no way of changing this.

Is there a method I can use (preferably pure CSS) that will allow me to target links with the onclick action and apply to style to it?

EDIT:

Used on this link

```
<a href="https://example.com" title="test" onclick="javascript:this.target="_blank"">Example</a>
```

This is applied

```
a[title="test"]::after{
    content:" \2197"!important;
}
```

But this isn't

```
a[onclick="javascript:this.target="_blank""]::after{
    content:" \2197"!important;
}
```

Comment: _“Is there a method I can use (preferably pure CSS) that will allow me to target links with the onclick action and apply styling to it?”_ - was there a method you were able to use that allowed you to target links with the `target` attribute having the value `_blank` and apply styling to it? Yes? Then what do you think would be fundamentally different about doing the same thing with some-other-attribute and some-other-value …?

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick is another attribute so you can target that in the same way; with the attribute selector, e.g;

```
a[target="_blank"]::after,
[onclick="javascript:this.target="_blank""]::after {
    content: " \2197";
}
```

After is a psuedo element so really it should be `::after`, not `:after`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately in this case so far I cannot get this to work. That could be very well tied to sharepoint weirdness though. The glyph does not appear, not in the browser's dev tools either. Yo're right about the ::, I have corrected this.

Comment: You probably just need to add some positioning context for the glyph. Kinda hard to say without seeing the context.

Comment: The thing is when I target these links without the onclick the glyph is showing up. And when I add a title attribute and use that to target, it shows up
Seems like the web parts in SP load their content after the initial page load so that the CSS isn't applied? Added some further explanation in the OP.